# Forms with Kohana 3.2 and Smarty

Tags: forms, kohana, smarty, kohana-3, smarty3

Good day! I'm learning Kohana (3.2) with Smarty (MrAnchovy-Kohana_Smarty). I created a simple form with one field which is validated after submission. I'd like the field to be repopulated with the submitted value when the validation fails. How can I do it please?

```
<div class="field_input">{form::input('cs_number')}</div>
```

Could you also recommend some framework for creating and validating forms in Kohana using Smarty?
Thank you in advance! Vojtech

Comment: Not related, but since you are using a template engine with Kohana, take a look at https://github.com/zombor/KOstache, mustache implementation for Kohana. I think it is more flexible than Smarty, implemented in a variety of languages, including javascript, so you can use the same templates for the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could you also recommend some framework for creating and validating forms in Kohana using Smarty?

You can use [Formo](https://github.com/bmidget/kohana-formo) library to create forms

> I'd like the field to be repopulated with the submitted value when the validation fails

You need to pass $_POST array to the template and echo it in input's value. Example: `<input type="text" name="test" value="<?php echo Arr::get($post, 'test) ?>" />`.